# Detect if user pressed @ sign in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How can I detect if user pressed the @ sign in pygame?

On some keyboard I need to press SHIFT + 2, on others ALT + V, etc.

This works:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        print("ENTER key pressed")
```

This doesn't:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_AT:
        print("@ sign pressed")
```

This works only on one type of keyboard:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_2:
        if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
            print("@ sign pressed")
```

So how can I detect if the user press @ without knowing the type of keyboard they use?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A `KEYDOWN` event also has a `unicode` attribute, so you can check `if event.unicode == "@":`

Comment: Im going to open a bounty on this once I can, this is a good question

Comment: `if event.unicode == "@":` worked! Thanks :) Please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments of [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7675174/eric) and [@Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739342/zoltan) the solution is:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.unicode == '@':
           print("@ sign pressed")
```

A `KEYDOWN` event also has a unicode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame `event.unicode` returns the actual output (in unicode format) if it was typed on something like notepad rather than a specified key.

So this should work:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.unicode == '@':
           print("@ sign pressed")
```